# Why doesn't exit() in a base class terminate child classes?

Tags: php, class, exit, phalcon

In the OnConstruct() method of the base class I use the exit() function after redirecting to the error page in order to terminate the subsequent code including all codes of the child classes.

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXI1t.jpg)

But it doesn't work. Here is the pseudocode below:

- when I access the page 'child/index' , it redirected to the error page, and I got two lines in '/tmp/debug.log' file:
- access: construct of base class
- access: index of child class

I don't know why the string "access: index of child class" in the child class is printed. My purpose is to terminate everything after exit(), including all child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the [controller documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/controllers#initializing).

> Be aware that onConstruct() method is executed even if the action to
>   be executed doesn't exist in the controller or the user does not have
>   access to it (according to custom control access provided by the
>   developer).
>
> The initialize() method is only called if the beforeExecuteRoute event
>   is executed with success. This avoid that application logic in the
>   initializer cannot be executed without authorization.

I would suggest to use the [event beforeExecuteRoute](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/dispatcher) which is triggered on events and controllers and allow you to stop the execution if you return false.

```
public function beforeExecuteRoute(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
{
    return false; //stop operation
}
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch! I will try it